# How to disable previous dates in input field designed using Bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3, datepicker

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label for="apointment-date"> Date</label>
     <div class="input-group date" id="datepicker">
         <input class="form-control" id="appintmentDate" type="date" required>
         <span class="input-group-addon">
             <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
         </span>
     </div>
</div>
<script language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
         $("#appintmentDate").datepicker({
             minDate: 0
         });
    });
</script>
```

I'm getting the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function

If I click on the date input field previous dates should be disabled. It should display only days from present days onwards.

Answer (score 0):

```
var date = new Date();
var today = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate());

$('#appintmentDate').datepicker({ 
    minDate: today
});
```

Try this once..

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an error because `datepicker` method has never be defined. Note that `datepicker` method is included in the [jQuery UI](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/) library while it's not part of the Bootstrap default components.

You have to include jQuery UI properly to avoid `TypeError` issue, then you have to change input type to text. Here a  working example:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#appintmentDate").datepicker({
        minDate: 0
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="apointment-date"> Date</label>
    <div class="input-group date" id="datepicker">
      <input class="form-control" id="appintmentDate" type="text" required>
      <span class="input-group-addon">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
      </span>
    </div>
</div>
```